# Multiple solr instances within Jetty or run Multiple Jetty servers, which is less intensive?

Tags: solr, jetty

I am about to embark upon a new linode VPS server.I currently use both Tomcat and Jetty (on my development server) to serve different Solr, but having read around a bit I realise Tomcat can be quite a resource hog, hence the suggestion for me to use Jetty. I already have a Jetty development server set up with an application in Jetty1/webapps/ROOT/

Here are my questions:

1) Is it better to run 2 solr instances within the same Jetty server

or

2) Should I run two different Jetty servers (port 8080,8081 can both used since these are just for web services)

Which of the above will be less resource intensive?

To be honest, my preference would be 2), to run 2 different jetty servers, because its going to be quite a lot of work to get one Jetty server to run multiple solr instances, since I already have an application running in Jetty1/solr/home and will have to set it up over again, including adapting to multiple instances . There also isnt much in the way of tutorials for this.

Also, I have another Solr instance set up in Tomcat. Can I just copy and paste the index over into Jetty2/solr,will the indexes work as normal, or will i need to re-index them in Jetty?

Cheers

Ke

Comment: have you considered a multi-core setup instead of multiple instances? http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultipleIndexes#MultiCore

Comment: I can see this gives me the following:

http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/admin/

http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/admin/

But would I be able to run it this way?

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/

http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/admin/

so only one app runs on a different core, they other runs in solr/home?

Comment: No, either they all run within their own core core or none does.

Comment: multi-core would have a smaller footprint since it all runs within the same instance.

Comment: I thought as much. Im going to need as much room to breathe as i can get in the linode 360 so this is helpful advice. Its just going to be a real pig to get the current app im using (not built by me) sitting in solr/home to perform in a multi-core environment :/ my guess is that i will have to get the source code for it and recompile :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running 2 different jetty instances will not be resource intensive and will give you the flexibility of bringing down one without the other, we run multiple Jettys behind Apache with no problems

If they are serving different purposes, this would be a good way to go, however, if they are related, then you should look to see if a multi-core setup is an option

There is no need to re-index in jetty, the index files are the same, even moving between linux and windows is not a problem.

Comment: Can you explain how to run multiple Jettys as daemons on Linux? what configuration need to be changed or so?

Comment: Just run each one under a different port